# Formalizing modus ponens on $PA$ arithmetic theory.

Tags: logic, recursion, computability

In the (short) book
[J] "Notes on logic and set theory" (Peter Johnstone).

The author P.J. considered the first order Peano  language of naturals (the $\bar{0}$, the successor $S$, $+$,  $\cdot$) and the PA theory (inductive usual condiction on addiction and moltiplication, and a system of inductive axioms for each formula), see [J] p. 29.

in the last chapter 9, he define the Godel coding  of PA language: $\sharp X\in N$ (X a term or formula ecc.) and define the relation (on couples of natural numbers):

$Ded_N(n, m):: $
*if $n= \sharp (p_1,\ldots p_n)$ where $(p_1,\ldots p_n)$ is a proof of a proposition $q=p_n$ and  $m=\sharp q$*.

this relation is recursive, this mean that its characteristic funtion is recursive, then  there is a formula $D(x, y,z)$  that $PA$-define it ([J] p. 50, T.4.13).

Define the $PA$ formula  $Def(x, y):=D(x, y, z)[z/1]$

we have $Def(\bar{n}, \bar{m})$ iff $Def_N(n, m)$, where $\bar{n}$ is the usual close term of the language, like a formal copy of $n$ .

Define $Th(y):=\exists x: Ded(x, y)$ ("mean" that $y$ is a code of a theorem of $PA$, in the $PA$ language).

Suppose that $PA\vdash p\to q$, then from a code $n$ of a proof of $p$ we can make (in recursive term) a code $\tilde{n}$ of a proof  of $q$ (just add to the proof the elements $p\to q, q$ and recodifing)

P.J. claim that this idea can be formalized, precisely he claim that:
if $PA\vdash p\to q\ $ then $\ PA\vdash\ Th(\sharp p)\to Th(\sharp q)$.

although it seems obvious and natural,  havent reach a formal syntactically exact proof of it, and haven't found examples of it in the bibliography known to me.

Could you help me?

Comment: Reasoning inside $\mathsf{PA}+Th(\#p)$, the idea is to combine the hypothesized $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $p$ with a $\mathsf{PA}$-proof of $p\rightarrow q$ (which we're assuming exists). It might help to note that from $\mathsf{PA}\vdash p\rightarrow q$ we get $\mathsf{PA}\vdash Th(\#(p\rightarrow q))$ (the converse fails unless we assume $\mathsf{PA}$ is $\Sigma_1$-sound of course); in particular, it may be easier to see that $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash [Th(\#p)\wedge Th(\#(p\rightarrow q))\rightarrow Th(\#q)].$$

Comment: all right and clear  until:
"in particular, it may be easier to see that ...". 

The definition of $Th(\sharp p)$ is a formula, but I dont know if $Ded(x,y)$ has a proof in $PA$.... I can get $Th(p)$ form a $Ded(n, \sharp p)$, I try many way (with help of other theorem) but all my attempts always had flaws.